# JQuery UI - toggleClass timing function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JQuery UI toggleClass to add a class to one of my Elements and I'm having difficulty getting the duration and the callback to take effect.

I was concerned that the JQuery toggleClass function was being called and not the overwridden JQuery UI function, so I put an alert into the JQuery UI method and found that it is in fact the JQuery UI method that is being called.  However, it ignores the duration parameter, and the completion parameter is called immediately.

```
     this.$el.toggleClass('success', 100000, 'easeOutSine', function () {
           alert('animation completed')
         })
```

[JQuery UI Documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/)

I've tried calling the toggleClass function in a number of different ways:

1. Passing the duration parameter as a string
2. Passing the duration parameter as a Number
3. Passing the duration parameter as an Object as per the documentation

   ```
      this.$el.toggleClass('success', {
          'duration': 100000,
          'complete': function () {
            alert('function completed')
          }
        })
   ```

I also tried:  `this.$el.toggleClass('success', 500000, 'easeOutSine', function () {
               console.log('completed')
             })`

as per the suggestion below.

The class is added or removed to the element, but the completed callback function runs immediately.

Comment: Could you add the HTML and CSS involved ?

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/mp68oy7h/4/). It's working fine as per the duration provided.

Comment: Cheers, I tried using that signature as well. and no joy unfortunately.  It must be something else.  I'm going to check the version of jQuery I'm using is compatible with the jQuery UI library.  I can't think of what else it might be.  The class is being added but the duration is being ignored

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the jQueryUI script in your page?

Transition functionality is available only in jQueryUI not in jQuery.

Please check following both links.

https://api.jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Thanks,
Amit Prajapati

Comment: Yes - and I've added an alert within the jqueryUI library so I could be certain it is the toggleClass method of the jQueryUI library that was being called

Comment: I think I mentioned that in the question above. " I was concerned that the JQuery toggleClass function was being called and not the overwridden JQuery UI function, so I put an alert into the JQuery UI method"

Answer (score 0):

I tried by using same toggleClass function but I didnt came across any error.Can you please confirm there is a `success` class defined in your code.

HTML

```
<div class="toggler">
  <div id="effect" class="success ui-corner-all">
      I will change my color on toggle
  </div>
</div>

<button id="button" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all">Run Effect</button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
      $( "#effect" ).toggleClass('success', 5000, 'easeOutSine',function(){
              alert('animation completed')
         });
    });
  });
```

Here is [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9tub9th4/3/)

Comment: Hi - yes there is a 'success' class in my CSS.  The class gets added no problem, but the delay is ignored.  I've tried using jQuery's delay() function instead, and there again I have the problem that the timer isn't taking any effect.  So I've resorted to using JavaScript setTimeout() instead.

Comment: If possible please post the html